# Change ondblclick to onclick event when using IOS/Android etc

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I change the *ondblclick* event to *onclick* event when page detects that its on IOS/Android etc. What makes it difficult is I cannot just call the ID of the element since it carry data from database to Javascript function.

Check it out.

**Server-side:**

```
<?php         
echo '<table>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<tr><td ondblclick="sampFunc("'.$row[0].'","'.$row[1].'")">';
        echo $row[0];
    echo '</td></tr>'; 
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

**Client-side:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        /* ?????????????????? */
    }
});
function sampFunc(data1,data2){
    //-- Something
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have to wait and check the device type on client side when you can check it from PHP and just change the code your outputting accordingly?  Check out the the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] value.

Comment: @Markipe - I really wouldn't advise User Agent sniffing, read here for reasons why: [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). Also, for an example of how I'd recommend doing it just see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should re-write some of you code to make it easier to achieve what you want.

Trying to *sniff* the user agent isn't a great idea. Devices can change, new OS's can be launched and it requires more maintenance on your end. Feature detection is a much better approach as it covers devices now and in the future as well as minimising false positives.

The updated PHP now uses the HTML5 [`data-*`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attribute and removes the inline event:

```
<?php         
echo '<table class="myclass">';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<tr><td data-a="'.$row[0].'" data-b="'.$row[1].'">';
        echo $row[0];
    echo '</td></tr>'; 
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The new JS checks whether it's a touchscreen device and defines a variable `touchDevice` as `true` or `false` depending on which it is. This var is then used to define the event. If it's `true` (device is touch capable) then `click` is the event, otherwise it's `dblclick`.

The event handler now uses [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of being defined inline and it makes use of the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

```
<script>
var touchDevice = !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window);

$(document).ready(function(){
    var dblevent = touchDevice ? 'click' : 'dblclick';
    $('.myclass td').on(dblevent, function(){
        var data1 = $(this).data('a'), data2 = $(this).data('b');
         //-- Something
    });   
});
</script>
```

or simply use the updated PHP and the `doubletap` event:

```
$('.myclass td').on('dblclick doubletap', function(){
      var data1 = $(this).data('a'), data2 = $(this).data('b');
      //-- Something 
});
```

Comment: sorry joe, I just got excited with php $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. Anyways I just tried your solution its very good and impressive. Two thumbs for you. Thanks..

Comment: @Markipe - thanks, it's no problem :) I just thought I'd show you an alternative.